# Converting datetime to timedelta so they can be added

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

When subtracting two `datetime` objects, I understand the result is `timedelta` object:

```
import datetime

AcDepart = 1900-01-01 18:00:00
AcArrival = 1900-01-01 07:00:00
ActualHours = AcDepart - AcArrival
```

I want to then subtract the sum of two other `date time` objects from `ActualHours`

These are the two other objects:

```
HrsEarly = 1900-01-01 02:00:00
HrsLate = 1900-01-01 00:30:00
```

This is the equation that fails to complete:

```
UnCalcTime = ActualHours - (HrsEarly + HrsLate)
```

This is the error:

```
UnCalcTime = ActualHours - (HrsEarly + HrsLate)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

So, I obviously can't add `datetime.datetime`. Does anyone know how I could get around this? Can `timedelta` be added together? If so, how can I convert `datetime` to `timedelta`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to solve this unsuccessfully for a long time.

Comment: You *could* subtract "1900-01-01 00:00:00" from your times to obtain deltas, but where are those `HrsEarly` coming from in the first place? They are not `HrsEarly`, but a specific point in time. Also, your code is not valid python (`AcDepart = 1900-01-01 18:00:00`)

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is to create your variables as `timedelta` in the first place.

```
HrsEarly = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
HrsLate = datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
```

If you can't do that, you can simply subtract your "zero date" from the `datetime` objects.

```
>>> HrsEarly
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 0)
>>> HrsEarly = HrsEarly - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
>>> HrsEarly
datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
```

Comment: Great answer.  Who knew that subtracting to datetime objects would instead return a timedelta object.  It wasnt obvious to me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Convert the string to timedelta

```
from datetime import datetime

AcDepart = '1900-01-01 18:00:00'
AcDepart_ = datetime.strptime(AcDepart, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
AcArrival = '1900-01-01 07:00:00'
AcArrival_ = datetime.strptime(AcArrival, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ActualHours = (AcDepart_ - AcArrival_).total_seconds()/3600
print ActualHours
```

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to add two `datetime` objects: It might seem, in your example, that "2AM on the 1st of January 1900" plus "half past midnight on the 1st of January 1900" should be "half past two on the 1st of January 1900", but in another context the desired result could as easily be "half past two on the 2nd of February 3800", or even (if the [UNIX epoch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26205/why-does-unix-time-start-at-1970-01-01) is used as an origin) "half past two on the first of January 1830".

Looking at a different example might make this more obvious: what should be the result of Tuesday + Saturday?

Your `HrsEarly` and `HrsLate` variables are presumably meant to store a time *difference*, and there's an appropriate type for that: `datetime.timedelta`. Adding two of those together does what you want:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> HrsEarly = timedelta(hours=2)
>>> HrsLate = timedelta(minutes=30)
>>> HrsTotal = (HrsEarly + HrsLate)
>>> str(HrsTotal)
'2:30:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this method using built-in `timestamp` function?

```
import datetime

a = "2017-01-01 14:30:00"
b = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
c = b.timestamp()
d = datetime.timedelta(seconds=c)
```

Runtime environment
  OS: Ubuntu 16.04
  Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Create a `modules.py`  and paste the following two functions. Import them wherever you want and use as is.

```
import datetime

def JsTimestampToPyDatetime(js_date):
    """
        converts javascript timestamp to python datetime taking care of 
        milliseconds and seconds

        Args:
            js_date(Timestamp, required)

        Returns:
            Datetime
    """

    try:
        # handles seconds
        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(js_date))
    except (ValueError):
        # handles miliseconds
        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(js_date) / 1000)
       
    return date

# consuming javascript generated timestamps

a = JsTimestampToPyDatetime(1627303810000) # with miliseconds
b = JsTimestampToPyDatetime(1627476610) # with seconds only


def GetDaysInDateTime(min_stamp, max_stamp):
    """
        Calculates time difference between two timestamps in days

        Args:
            min_stamp(Datetime, required): Minimum/start datetime
            max_stamp(Datetime, required): Maximum/end datetime

        Returns:
            Int: Days
    """

    days = (max_stamp-min_stamp).days
    return int(days)


print(GetDaysInDateTime(a, b))
```